# Как задать размер QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Как задать размер QTextEdit , я задаю так 
Код:

```
QTextEdit* textEditTop = new QTextEdit;
textEditTop->setPlainText("");
textEditTop->resize(10, 10);
```

но размер не изменяется.
Я в конструкторе делаю одну кнопку и два едита.
Код:

```
mBackButton = new QPushButton("Назад");

QTextEdit* textEditTop = new QTextEdit;
textEditTop->setPlainText("");
textEditTop->resize(10, 10);

QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
hLayout->addWidget(mBackButton);
hLayout->addWidget(textEditTop);



QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit;
textEdit->setPlainText("");
textEditTop->resize(100, 100);
textEditTop->setWindowModified(Qt::ScrollBarPolicy::ScrollBarAsNeeded);

QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addLayout(hLayout);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
setLayout(layout);

resize(800, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вместо `textEditTop->`[resize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resize-1) вызывать `textEditTop->`[setFixedSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1).

---

Когда вы помещаете виджет на компоновщик (`Q*Layout`), вы доверяете ему установку положения и размера виджетов.

Но можно принудительно указать размер виджета через такие методы как:

- [setMinimumHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop), [setMinimumWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumWidth-prop), [setMinimumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop)
- [setMaximumHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumHeight-prop), [setMaximumWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumWidth-prop), [setMaximumSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumSize-prop)
- [setFixedHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight), [setFixedWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth), [setFixedSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)

Или настроить политику изменения размера через [setSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1)

Comment: спасибо, а как скрол  вертикальный можно сделать? я делаю через  QScrollBar  но не работает

Comment: Думаю что-то вроде такого будет: `QScrollBar * scroll = textEditTop->verticalScrollBar();` `scroll->setValue(scroll->maximum())`

Comment: нет не  работает(

Comment: люблю такие информативные ответы :) ок, я сомневаюсь что правильно понял насчет скрола, под сделать вы подразумевали отобразить его или переместить вертикальный скрол вниз?

Comment: извените,  да я  хочу  отображать горизонтально скрол в втором edit: QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit; я  делаю  так:  QScrollBar* scroll = textEdit->horizontalScrollBar();
    scroll->setValue(scroll->maximum());

Comment: Чтобы всегда показывать скрол нужно вызвать метод setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy/setVerticalScrollBarPolicy и установить значение Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ScrollBarPolicy-enum